# failed to add elements directly to python nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to add lements to nested python dictionary

```
res_checks = dict()
res_checks['arg1']['sub1'] = 'test'

print(res_checks)
```

but I always get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    res_checks['arg1']['sub1'] = 'test'
KeyError: 'arg1'
```

try to add it in different formats but it is always fail

Comment: `res_checks.setdefault('arg1', {})['sub1'] = 'test'`. Better yet, `res_checks = collections.defaultdict(dict)`

Comment: Doing `res_checks['arg1'] = {}` first will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't know that `res_checks['arg1']` is supposed to be a dictionary, so it can't index it. You have to declare it as an empty dictionary first.

```
res_checks = dict()
res_checks['arg1'] = {}
res_checks['arg1']['sub1'] = 'test'

print(res_checks)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a one-shot approach:

```
res_checks = dict(arg1={'sub1': 'test'})

print(res_checks)
```

Result:

```
{'arg1': {'sub1': 'test'}}
```